# jQuery - do .serialize() the right escape?

Tags: jquery

I've already done a function using .serialize().

This is the function :

```
$('form[name=contactForm]').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        url: './ajax/header_ajax.php',
        data: 'id=header_contact_send&'+$(this).serialize(), 
        success: function(msg) {
            $("#boxContentId").html(msg);
        }
    });
});
```

If I put into my input box some value as **'**, **"** or **,** 
I see they are correctly processend, and the function work. How is possible? It should make confusion on `'id=header_contact_send&'+$(this).serialize(),`

Do the serialize() function the escape of the strings?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

basically, serialize in implemented in [this file](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js). It ends up calling, for each value pair, a function that is defined inside jQuery.param :

```
add = function( key, value ) {
// If value is a function, invoke it and return its value
value = jQuery.isFunction( value ) ? value() : value;
s[ s.length ] = encodeURIComponent( key ) + "=" + encodeURIComponent( value );
};
```

so the escaping is done by calling the native javascript function [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

I hope this will help you,

Jerome Wagner

Comment: Nice! So I think i can trust on that function, without do anything more :)